# Finding the residue of $\frac{e^z-1-z}{\sin z -z}$ at $z=0$ by taylor expansion.

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I am trying to find the residue of $\frac{e^z-1-z}{\sin z -z}$ at $z=0$. What I have done so far is to taylor expand the numerator and denominator:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}z^2+O(z^3)}{-\frac{1}{6}z^3+O(z^5)}$$

However, I am now stuck and dont see how to divide this rational function to find the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$ term.

Any tips? Any other methods to suggest?

Comment: Write it as $$\frac{\frac{1}{2}z^2 + O(z^3)}{-\frac{1}{6}z^3\cdot (1 + O(z^2))}$$ and think of a geometric series.

Comment: Very clever, I get it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notice that $0$ is a zero of order $2$ of the numerator and of order $3$ of the denominator. Hence it is a simple pole and the residue is simply given by $$\text{Res}_0(f) = \lim_{z\to 0} zf(z).$$ In your case \begin{align*}\lim_{z\to 0} z\frac{e^z-1-z}{\sin z -z}&=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(e^z-1-z)+z(e^z-1)}{\cos(z)-1}\\
& = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{e^z-1+ze^z+e^z-1}{-\sin(z)}\\
& = \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{3e^z+ze^z}{-\cos(z)}\\
& = -3
\end{align*}

where I have applied multiple times the complex version of De l'Hospital theorem.

Comment: How do you find the order of the numerator and the denominator without series expanding around $z=0$?

Comment: Let's note $g(z)$ the numerator and $h(z)$ the denominator. You can find that $g(0)=g'(0)=0$ and $g''(0)\neq 0$ so it is a zero of order $2$. For the denominator we have $h(0)=h'(0)=h''(0)=0$ and $h'''(0) \neq 0$ so it is a zero of order $3$. What I used is the definition of the order of a zero.

Answer (score 1):

Since the power series expansion of $\sin(z)$ is 
$$
\sin(z)=z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots
$$
the power series expansion of $\sin(z)-z$ is
$$
\sin(z)-z=-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\cdots=z^3\left(-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{z^2}{5!}-\cdots\right)
$$
Therefore, $\sin(z)-z=z^3g(z)$ where $g(z)$ is an entire function and $g(0)=-\frac{1}{3!}\not=0$.

On the other hand, the power series expansion of $e^z$ is
$$
e^z=1+z+\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots.
$$
Therefore, the power series expansion of $e^z-1-z$ is
$$
e^z-1-z=\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots
$$

Therefore, 
$$
\frac{e^z-1-z}{\sin(z)-z}=\frac{\frac{z^2}{2}+\frac{z^3}{3!}+\cdots}{z^3g(z)}=\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{2g(z)}+\frac{1}{3!g(z)}+\cdots.
$$
Thus, the residue at $z=0$ is $\frac{1}{2g(0)}-\frac{3!}{2}=-3$.

Alternately, the numerator can be written as $e^z-1-z=z^2h(z)$ where $h(0)=\frac{1}{2}$, then your residue becomes $\frac{h(0)}{g(0)}$.